# switching SDK in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, emulation

I have installed the SDKs(1.5,1.6,2.1,2.2) from AVD manager, and created a new emulator device with version 1.5. However, I cannot find this device in run configuration target. It only displays the devices created with version 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the minimumSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion version in your XML ?

Comment: I'm setting the min sdk version to 3, and target to 8

Comment: Run configuration target lists all the devices I created after I changed the targetSdkVersion. After I created a new configuration with that device, the target choices for devices with 1.5 and 1.6 disappear.

Comment: setting sdk version to 3, and target to 3 should be able to launch the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug. "Run Configurations"/"Debug Configurations" filter out all emulators that have API Level lower than what is specified in `target` property in `default.properties` file of Android project.

There is one workaround.

1. In your "Run Configurations"/"Debug Configurations" select your configuration, go to "Target" tab and click on "Manual" radio button. This will show you list of running emulators when you want to start/debug you app.
2. Start Android 1.5 emulator manually (from AVD Manager), wait until eclipse sees this emulator as "online" in "Devices" view.
3. Start you application and select the Android 1.5 emulator to run on.